# CKEditor Copy and Cut Disabled

Tags: ckeditor, xpages

I created a custom toolbar for my CKEditor and noticed that the Cut and Copy are greyed out making them not clickable.  I also tried to use the ‘Full’ toolbarType and Simple Binding rather than a scoped variable with same result.  My CKEditor is contained in a table cell within a div.  I am using the CSS from this blog [post](http://www.scottgood.com/jsg/blog.nsf/d6plinks/SGOD-889H6V) and found this [article](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/3613) that talks about the z-index value being the issue when using an absolute positioned container.  I had no idea what the z-index value was for the baseFloat, but did find this [article](http://docs.cksource.com/ckeditor_api/symbols/CKEDITOR.config.html#.baseFloatZIndex) giving a default value.

You will see that the z-index value in the CSS is lower than the default value so that shouldn't be the issue.  I even changed the background div to a -1 and the foreground div to a 1.

I am using 8.5.3, IE 9/Chrome 30.0.1599.69 m

[image]

I wasn't able to find any other posts under the xpages or ckeditor tag that had a resolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Domino 8.5.3 uses CKEditor 3.5.3. This appears to be [a bug in CKEditor](http://dev.ckeditor.com/ticket/8463) and has been fixed in CKEditor 3.6.3.

Domino 9.0 uses CKEditor 3.6.3 and I can re-produce the error on Domino 8.5.3 and confirm that it has been fixed in Domino 9.0.

Comment: Is there a way to get CKEditor 3.6.3 without using 9.0?

Comment: I know that Russell Maher has upgraded to CKEditor 4.0 so it should be possible. But the easiest way to get to use CKEditor 3.6.3 is probably to upgrade Domino to 9 :-)

Comment: @RussellMaher I think by adding his twitter handle Russell will actually receive a notification from this comment and can read your previous comment, then reply how he did this along with stating the level at which this upgrade applies